# How to use Glue job bookmark to read mongodb data and track last processed row using "updated_at" column?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have implemented aws glue job bookmark to read data from MongoDB and write to the s3 bucket, but when we run the script, it writes all data in a separate file every time. I only want incremental data to be loaded every time we run the job, using the updated_at column as the bookmark key. But the bookmark is not working. How can I achieve that?

```
read_mongo_options = {
"URI": mongo_uri,
"database": "test",
"collection": "test",
"username": "test",
"password": "test",
"jobBookmarkKeys":["updated_at"],
"jobBookmarkKeysSortOrder":"asc"}

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type="mongodb",connection_options=read_mongo_options, transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
```

I have tried to give bookmark details in additional_options as well while creating the dynamic_frame, but that too didn't work. On every job run new parquet file is created in S3 with the same size, loading the whole data again instead of incremental data.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html):

```
If user-defined bookmarks keys are used, they must be strictly monotonically increasing or decreasing. Gaps are permitted.
```

Just the timestamp will not be sufficient for bookmarking. You would need a combination of unique ID and last updated at timestamp.